# How to handle responsive svg type image in side div tag

Tags: css, svg, responsive, mudblazor

i am supposed to create this card using CSS. following you can see Figma UI design of it.

[image]

following you can see my code part of it (I have used one mudblazor icon for this )

```
    <div class="dashboard-tile-card">
                                       
         <div class="dashboard-tile-icon ">
               <img src="/img/moneybag.svg" width="50%" />
         </div>
         <div class="dashboard-card-action">
                                            
              <a class="text-white">Go to the Dashboard</a><MudIcon Style="@($"color:{Colors.Grey.Lighten5};")" Icon="@Icons.Filled.ArrowForward"></MudIcon>
         </div>
  </div>
```

moneybag.svg

```
    <svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g filter="url(#filter0_b_0_1)">
<circle cx="60" cy="60" r="60" fill="url(#paint0_radial_0_1)"/>
<circle cx="60" cy="60" r="58.5" stroke="url(#paint1_radial_0_1)" stroke-width="3"/>
<circle cx="60" cy="60" r="58.5" stroke="url(#paint2_radial_0_1)" stroke-width="3"/>
<circle cx="60" cy="60" r="58.5" stroke="url(#paint3_linear_0_1)" stroke-width="3"/>
</g>
<rect x="30" y="30" width="60" height="60" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_b_0_1" x="-42" y="-42" width="204" height="204" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="21"/>
<feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur_0_1"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur_0_1" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0_0_1" transform="scale(0.003125)"/>
</pattern>
<radialGradient id="paint0_radial_0_1" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1.07937 3.57024) rotate(44.0741) scale(162.963 260.636)">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.4"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint1_radial_0_1" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1.07937 3.57024) rotate(44.0741) scale(162.963 260.636)">
<stop stop-color="#D8D8D8" stop-opacity="0"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#D8D8D8"/>
</radialGradient>
<radialGradient id="paint2_radial_0_1" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1.65079 116.331) rotate(-44.0635) scale(162.139 259.045)">
<stop stop-color="#D8D8D8" stop-opacity="0"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#D8D8D8"/>
</radialGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint3_linear_0_1" x1="2.22222" y1="3.27273" x2="141.088" y2="66.7179" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.9"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<image id="image0_0_1" width="320" height="320" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAAFACAYAAADNkKWqAAAZtUlEQVR4nO3df2id133H8XcT0ZlOlJviFlFEUcBQr7AiRv7wWqVzOne4rIuVobKOOouC3WXQtHPYTFLqJmTZqEMYSbuOUJxMdpIxSrLZIYS4S4vc2F1cstVaVxaHhklbvFnDYha1O6utU++P773TtXol3Xufc57veZ7zecHBimI/z1dXV1+d5/z4nrcgEsYgMNHh8zPNJiJSK8PACDANvAxc6dBmm/9/Z/PvbnCJVEQkkAZwP3CezklvrfawQ7wiIkFsBV6k98TXaj/FeoXbyg5cRKSI3fSf+Fa2s8BYueGLiPRnH+GSX3tTEhSRZA0Ae4BLxEmAZ9HjsIgkaoQ4ia+9ncfGFkVEkjFEsQmPXpPgcDlflojI+iYpJ/m12gPlfFkiImsbo9zk12qTZXxxIiKr2QA8jU8CfLWEr09EZFVb8Ul+rTYe/0sUgWu8A5AkbXa+/x3YdjsRkdLN4tsDvIKWxUgJ1AOUlUax0lbetENEonuLdwCSlAHgIWznh7czwC8DixHvMcRyea5drJ50F4C9wBIwHzEeEXFUxq6PXtr9kb7O8ea1e33Un40Yk4g4245/0mtvIXeHbMDGFV8BLhSM60k0SSNSO9P4J72VbSTA1zVG+HWNmqQRqZED+Ce7Tm26wNc0BByPFNdsgbhEJCH34J/oVmvnsfNEejGETeScihjXJbRtT6TyRoibKEK1bneHjFLeOsZ7u4xJRBKzATug6Cz+ya2bdgH4AzqPCY40/98scK7EmDQjXHED3gGIizHgD+l8jm+qBoFH6XzO8GizifRECTAvE1jiq/IuCyU7CUYJ0F/7boSViuw8GGb5+3s3VuBgyxr3kt696R2AFKME6GMPcF3z499j9bVuc8ATbf/9JnDtir+z2ufuQot1RSQRQ9gj6Cx2OLj3pIKaJkFESrGbeAty1XzaOTQWKbKuWAeKq/k27QSpAdUDjKuBVTeW+lnwDkCKUwKMpwEcRmfd1tVe7wCkOCXAeBqoYkhdPQOc9A5CilMCjGeXdwASzZewNZpScUqA8VR5t4Ws7kSzSQ0oAYp0bwnr/UlNKAGKdO8kNv4nNaEEKNI9zfzWjBJgPI97ByBBHQFOewchYSkBxqOB8vq4CBxq/ik1ogQYz2XiHuot5TmN9QClZlaWUZJwfgj8AnCTdyBS2Cex0mQi0oMG8Ab+G/fV+m9PoyKytaVH4LgWga96ByGFXES7PmrrLd4BZGAz8BywyTsQ6Yt+RmpMPcD4NIBeXfu9A5C4lADLoQW01fSadwASlxJgeZQEq0Xb3jKgBFgeVRCuliW08Ln2NMBbrmlUJLUqrkdr/2pPPcByPegdgHTlIP0fSC8VogRYrpPAMe8gZF2zaO1fFrQVrlxL2LDDdmDAORbp7AwwiRJgFjQG6GMWGPEOQjqaw8b/JAN6BPahUlnput07ACmPEqCPv0RLLETcKQH60CLbNM2gpS9ZUQL0o21W6VECzIwmQXxd8Q5ArnIjGp/NinqAvjTgnhYlv8woAfo6ij12iT/t1c6QEqCveXRwUipUrSdDSoD+9IMn4kQJ0J8qRvs7jcb/sqQE6O8icMo7iMzNA697ByHlUwJMwxOo/JInTYBkStVg0rAIDANbvAPJ1G+iyagsqQeYjme9AxDJjRJgOjQQL1IyJcB0zAOHvIPI0H1o/2+2lADT8ph3ACI5UQJMj9YEipRECTA9X0UzkiKlUAJMjwokiJRE6wDTtAn4kHcQGZgDfts7CPGjHmCa9BgsUgIlwDSdAR72DkKk7pQA0/VlLBGKSCRKgOlaBC57ByFSZ0qAadOZISIRKQGmbQZbFiMiESgBpm0R1QkUiUbnAqdvI3DOO4iamgOu9w5C/KgHmL4FVCRBJAolwGo4hB6FRYJTAqyGE6hYqkhwSoDVofODRQJTAqyOM8Aj3kHUzGnvAMSXEmB1XAbOewdRMw96ByAivZkFrqgVbj8ANvf42kvNqB5g9fwY+Jh3EDXwQfQInD09AlePKkYXdwQlP0E9wCpaBK4DtnkHUlEHgU8BP/EORET6dwD/cbQqtXPAJDDYz4stIul5AP/EUoU2hSY8RGpnA7AVeAW4gH+iSa292Hx9RKTmxoHD+CedFNoUcC/QKPSKikilDAI3ANPAKfwTUZntfPPrHsF6xiKSsSFs0N87McVurcmN7WFeNsmJCqLmYxzY0fx40jOQgmaa7XFUIUcKUgLMU2tiYAeWGMEenzf6hLOqRZYPiG8dEDXXbCKFKQFKyyhwc9t/39L8XNmOAN8D3gReAo45xCCZUAKU1Wyk86LhqcD3WXn05wJwMfA9RERERERE0COwyGqGgYHmx/PAkmMsIiKl2YotrNbOEhHJxhAwwdXJr729gVXk3gpscYpRRCSK43S/A+UC1jO8xyVSkcwMYjs4JoFNzrHUzQS9Jb9O7XjzOiISyAZsc/9O4GWWf9hexWoBatN/MUPAHuASYfYlX8IKMjyKfd9EpA8NbNB9irV/4KZQvbt+jRL/hL37USIU6UoDS2b7sMH2bn/IzgMvoETYrS3Ak1gVmTKq1ZzFEu0E1uMUkRXGsSRW9IdNpd9XtxF7fTwrZx8Hdsf+QkWqYhIbzwv9g3YY1ceD5ZqIqR0gpQOaJFsNLDlNE/eHrFUh+QFsHCqXRbwjVKcq9svYBFdqZchEopgkfuJbrU1T7UKo69mDTTp4J7V+2qlm/FIy7QWOr4HNOE5hj2SeS1eWsH2tAA8Cp7GCozNuEfVuhOWZ1TFgV/Pj9r27VXQZOAPsxSpdz6/91yUEJcC4xoE7SHs8bh442vx4AfsBTM1u4IPNj0fxKdRaphPAIeAx70DqTgkwjk3Ac1R/RvYEdvbGSkcp3kMZYvVfDKGLrlbVfuBrVKuHXilKgGENYz2+Caqf/NYyw/JZHf1qDQ3I2uawXzh7UaVsSdjKEkpqaiHbYZYPsBJJxlZsEbOSn1rsdgF4BW2vC+Za7wAqbjfwt9iYnwoTSGxvBd6N/dK9Dp2LXJjGAPszCryIFrCKvxtRIuzbNd4BVMwgVuroMEp+koansdn0XHb6iJNxLPF5jwOpqXVq0ygJ9kxjgOsbAT6B9fze7xyLyGpahXN/EXjJOZbKUAJc20bgeWyy463OsYis5+3Ah7Fk+Bq2s0ekL7FKVampldHOoYXm0ocNWAkp7zewmlrRNosN3ajuoHTtYfzfuGpqIdthpCONAS7bBnyz+aeWB0mdbMYW65/FSm5JkxZCmzFsPZUOrZE6uwjcChzxDiQVuSfAISzxjXkHIlKiW4GnvINIQc4JsIElv23egYiUrFUF/ONkvlQm1wTYwAaGdZau5GwGuAWrOZilHAf7W4+9Sn6Su1Gscnm25bVymwXeDfwZSn4iLe9C5bWysA//9Vhqaim3A2Qmhx7gAPBZ7MzYKh+bKBLbr2A/Iy9jx3TWXg4J8LPY7g4lP5H1fQjbOvd170DKUPcEuA/1/ER6dQPwDuBb1LwnWOcEuBv1/ET6cQ2wpfnxtGcgsdU1Ae7Dkp+I9O9D2FnXz3kHEkvdekcDwJ3A570DydBlbKP9XnrbXTCGfb90ql6adgPz2PKxJedYZB178F9KkGub7eL7sxp939JveqJK3D7gEv5vlFzbxPrfolWNJBC/2trtp1gSrFVPvS5b4XZjVZxr9c2pmKw31WdgAOup12p4qQ4JcB8ZrmAXcVKrn7eqJ8AGcId3ECKZqc0TV5UTYKuk1bB3ICIZ2gd80TuIoqqaAFXSSsTfnVR8YqSqCVCVnEX8tSZGKnuWThUT4BQ6w0MkJS9gp85VTtUS4DZgu3cQInKVzdh2uY3egfSqSglwKzq6UiRVm4EXqVh5/aokwGFsxrfhHYiIrGqUij2hVSUB3oGSn0gVPASMewfRrSpUgzmALbyU+prDjmfc0eH/TWAViqUaBrGntUocvp76ucAbgXPeQciqzmBlsG7HzphdjHCPLdg6szFgV/Nzw1Tjl3fOTgIfAS56B7KWlBPgCPabZNQ7ELnKDPZ9AfgycZLeevZgxzje63Bv6d4RrGcvfXgF/xJAasvtZWAnaS11GMHOr5gGTuH/Gqn9fHto1e+erGocuID/N0/NhiAmSX8cbgiL0/v1Uru6/QBbIiNd2on/N03NWlUnnx7A/7VTW27nSHQoK7VDkQaBv0AVXrx9A5tw+DvvQPr0MvYeSvKHLkNvw84T+SbwM+dYknYY/99WObfz2MRC1ddcNrBxQe/XU+3qtmetb1ruNuP/Dcq5naU+FXZ0xkia7RSJbWVNaSfI3d4BZO7j2KNvHexa/6+Ig1FsP7+ssA//3065trPUr7yYHn/TbnV7vxXSAN7A/5uSa6vU5vUubMfGMr1fV7XVWzLDLd6PwDrXw9cxbMtSnQxR/UmcuhsikZPlvBPgFnSuh5dvYNuUPLayxfRe7wCkK8MkMCvsvRd4GiVALzdhPcC6ueIdgHRtBiuYsOAVgGcP8ABKfl4OUs/kp8H1anEvoOrVA1SZK1+/BJwu6V4N1h+Tm8d2ChQ1he0HlupYBH4XOOpxc6+aaqoQ4ecI5SS/Vqmqm1i/p38QmGV5a+Z9sYKS5DSwiu8uCdDDFlTpxaudJ+4jxwhWxmy2YJyzbW2C7oZK9L6qdsumYsyT+L/YubbpLr4//bqHuDX5plj7h2RrxHurxW9ZlM0axcb+vF/sXFusBFh2Hb4/5ucP4i7a61Tzb/uosQHgYfxf5JxbjMffjcCrDl/Lq1jdvxFsPdklhxjUwrY3qPEidlXo8G8xDq2eSuDrUqtPK/WclzLXAWrm19ccYZaatGuQWHkjqby7KHFrbFkJcAwtUvX2BLbeLiT3haxSO61lMaUoKwHehnoK3t70DkCkSxP8/CRXFGUkwI1U93AdESnfZuxkyOjKSIAa+6uvOWxDu0hopeSN2AlQg+T1pgQoMUVPgrEToAbJ0xHrCNTHI11XZJzIu0NiJ8CpyNeX7sWaBDkB3Ej4GWaRTdiESDQxE+AkevxNyXXEq/5zAriV+lWXFn9RT/iL9VjUAL5ISVPZ0pUtWI88VpL6N+A7zY9HI91D8vQdbLw5uFgJcAh4JNK1pX9fIm4vbQ74evPjd2FLoESK2ND88+vA5dAXj/UIrIOp01TG92UJ+ALwW8DeEu4n9RdtOC1WD/Be4my8l2J+Bhwq6V7/A/wD8M9YUhwE3lHSvaV+/gn4XuiLxugBbkdjQKnagCWiMh0Bbsd6hF8AzpR8f6mHKE8vMXqAY8AnIlxXihvGKu96LF5eAF7CJmIuAf+OflFKb75F4OVWMU6FO4cGv1O2ALzTOwisNzqEJcRRalwIU4LZD3wu5AVjJMArEa4pYX0KeMw7iDbbsWT4EPrlKWvzOsq3K6oOXJ2W6qH0u4Hj+L8+amm2oHVFQ44BbsDG/t4X8JoSzzDwHOGrRBf1XeAF4HlszeII5U/cSLquAZ71DqITHUtYvVbq+Qt9GiHucZtq1WqnCLjELuQymNqf6VlDdwHbvINYxxzwEWyv8UnnWMTfKImuMda5rNVsZ6nOeS2D2K4AnS2ddws2fh1yRmWWRDOzdOVGrKpLFWzGxi9VbCNPc8D1IS4U6hFYpa+q72lsOUoV1uOdZnlnSWqTOBLfAIHep6FmgW8Bfj3QtcTHILATK5v1LOknltbOkh+hquO5eTu2m+hbRS8Uoge4AXhPgOtIGrZivcFU1wmu9BVsMif1hC01NYL/oKhanFal40z34f96qZXXThFg11BZB6NLNR3AZlwnSX8x8p9iW/wkD6MEeE+GGAPcBPx+gOtImt6Gnc71YeDHwH8B/+sa0eq+ix3+9AHinX8i6fhr7P3oahr/7rBauY8ee0ib3pN5tGkK0iOw9GoUq9oyix1ZmOLyp88Q6RAdqRclQOnHADb59XSzTZHWVsjvY0uzFrwDkbQV3QkyiQ4/l2VHsDWEJ4DXnWMB7U6qu9aC+L7fa0UnQUaxAXIRsF7gOPAb2KPxD4AfOsbzY+BjjveXuDZiY9J9H/GgR2CJYTO2Lu9fsJJbk05xHMXn/BOpCCVAiakB3A88ij2ObqXcvcZzwNdKvJ9UTNExwONUp5SSpOEo8FVsvLAsV0q8l5TrBFbJqC9FE6DeWNKvwgPYPdD7tN76zmN6BBYvrZp+D2AFNWLSchjpSAlQPLUmS74Y+T57I19fKkoJUFJwJ/Aw8XuCIldRApQUDGD7i1PcVic1ViQBageIhKb3lPSj75Uo6gFKSkaJU95eC6LrbVe//1AJUFLSIM5j8DywGOG6UnFKgCKSLSVAycEYaZXrkkQoAUoONqEZZulACVBEsqUEKCmZQ7O1UiIlwDzNAx/FDhRPKeHESoDvjXBNqQElwDwdbbZHsER4u284/+/xSNe9J9J1peKUAPPUnvDmgYNYSaHP4dMjvIgdYvSUw70lY0qA+VmrNNR+LBHdhCWjMspIXcSOsYxVIFW9P1nVgHcAUrr1SkPNNdsxbGvazc3P30X4cvZHgEPErQ6t8T9ZlRKgrGWG5Ufiv8LeL2Ms773cQm8lrOaxStBgifg01gOMZQt2eLtIR0qAeTmNnaHQjzPNP+dYHqubAAZ7uMbrBe7fj0/TW3ySGSXAvMwT9gyOZwJeK7RYlWWkRjQJkpdczsYYAG7DDs4WWVWRBPhssCikLLmcjXEnVmFaZE06FjMfc8CvYo/BdTYEvIA9Akse3kmfTzd6BM7HE9Q/+QE8jZJfbvoe2lECzMeb3gFENgQcp8D5EJIfPQLnYR57/J3zDiSSBtbz2+YdiLjoO49pGUwelqh38jsMbPUORKpHj8B5qOvs7xDW81Pyk74UTYCPBYlCYtvhHUAkeuyVQjmoaAL8dsF/L+XYiT0m1mVnxD5s/FkTHlIoB+kROB/jwN8A08AIvRUxSMEgcAMW/+edY5GaUALMSwMbL5sFHqU6Y2fjwJPAK1jMVUvekqiis8DzwCLh68RJfJNYYlnEStGfwEpfLXoG1WYUe189hJ3pq6oustIiBRf3F10HCPZIUpWehKztKPaG2otf4YTdwAex8Uqd5StrOYZVL++b1gFKu9YkyWTb5/YDr2GJ8Wik++7EHnFFSqUEKOtpnamxSOcDkx7HEmORHuOu9f+KSHghEuCz6BE4B60JlJW2YqfKpXK0puSjcEm+ELPAMQ+0ERFZTeHco2UwIpKtEAlwDviTANcREenWfQQo8KEeoIhkK1QCnCadBbQiUm+LwEshLhQqAR5DCVBEyrGI5ZzC9AgsItkKmQC1DkxEyhAs14RMgEvAxYDXExFZ6SKWa4IImQBPAs8EvJ6IyErPYLkmiNBjgK8Fvp6ISLugOSZ0Atwf+HpSf2NYvT+RbgTNMTFmgU9EuKakbRMw0ee/vQ3V/ZPuBM8tIQqirjSB1XZT2fK8LNHf2IwqCUk3loBbCTzPECMBgqpEi0hYhas/dxJrIfTpSNcVkTztjXHRWD3AEezkMRGREK4nQPWXla4NfcGmRezg6uBdVhHJzn0EqP7cScy9wE9Q8Mg6Ecne97FcEkWsHiBYL3AY2BLxHiJSb79D58O4gohdDeYQ6gWKSH+CbnvrJNYkSLsx4HgJ9xGRermRyBsryqgHeALtDhGR3pSSN2KOAba7ANyMDmIXkfXNADsoobxeWQnwX4EfAdtLup+IVNeDwDfKuFFZCRDgH4G3o1lhEelsCdvx8RXgZ2XcsIxJkHajwIvAxpLvKyLpm8N2fJSm7EORZrCZnddLvq+IpO114KNl37TMR+CWBeA9wAcc7i0i6VkAPoJDERWPBAj2GDyKKgGLCHyakiY9VvJKgADPA+/GEqGI5Okg8OfATzxu7pkAfwJ8E3gf6gmK5OgI8Ckcj9P1TIBgSfBr2JkS73eORUTK8xRW6MCl59finQBbprHKMUqCIvX3FPAZAh5w3q+y1wGu5zAw7h2EiERzBLjFO4iWVHqALc8D78AWSjecYxGRcOawpS4HcH7sbZdaD7BFO0ZE6qO1zi9aYdN+lb0TpFvaMSJSDwexn+Xkkh+k9wjcbgHrBf43tmtEpbREquMM8BDwR9jPcpJSToBgL9xLwH9iY4IjvuGISBeOAb8G/L13IOtJPQG2zGDH4m3CJkkGfcMRkQ7mgaPAJ7FD0ZKX6iTIWnTGiEh6HsMOQavU8RdVTIAt92ArybWXWMTPDLaba793IP2ocgIEGxPcDtyNxgdFyrKA7d99EHvknfMNp39VT4Dt7gVuR4lQJKZHsEfdJJe19KpOCRBgCPgEcBt6NBYJZR4b29uLLW+57BtOOHVLgC1D2KPxlHcgIhVXycmNbtU1AbbbiC3IbCVFEVnbUazXt5eEFzGHkEMCbGlgj8VT2K6SYd9wRJKx2GyPYz29GSqyjq+onBJguwbwWewIvknnWES8zGAl6F7Cdm9kJ9cE2LIBezQeA3ZhM8iaRZa6WgJOYqevPYgtZan1I+56ck+AK42yPHusCRSpi8eAb2MJ7xnnWJKiBLi+cWBH82M9LkvqTmBl5BawSQxZgxJgb7Y2/9zBcun+QVS4Vcq3hM3UwtXJ7nTb52UdSoDFjQI3t/33LWgRtsTRmrQA+A+s2KgUoAQY3kaWy3W1Pz6DJUaddSJrOcnyaWkrH2Ozn7QITQmwXNuxWed2d6OD4XPVaaHxMzgeFJ4bJcA03QO8d8XnBoEJh1ikNzN0LhRQ+10VVaQEWB0bgC3r/J3Wesb1aK1jZ92UdWrtlljrGpUtD5UbJcA83RvgGjexPCvu7Ri2m6Hlzeaf1/b4ufvChyYpUwKUfjVIZ0KntZdVREREuvF/rw9J5TJv+e4AAAAASUVORK5CYII="/>
</defs>
</svg>
```

CSS file

```
.dashboard-tile-card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1.5px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-radius: 12px;

}

.dashboard-tile-icon {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 75%;
}
.dashboard-card-action {
    background: #063b71ff;
    height: 25%;
    border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am not much good at the CSS side.i think I am doing some wrong CSS rules for this. my issue is I can't maintain the responsiveness of the image .some screen size svg image will be very small and for some screen sizes, this image will break the margin of the outside border.
please does anybody know how to do this very smart way instead of this? it should be responsive to whatever screen sizes

Comment: Remove the width and the height attributes from `<SVG>`. Then the SVG will take up the space available (50 % now that the `<img>` has that width).

Answer (score 0):

Try import this icon from figma in svg but inspect source code with browser. Then copy this small code and paste it in dashboard-tile-icon. Next what you want to do is removing height and width in svg tag and and give it in css using % if you want it responsive but I like this type of icons always keeps in between 50px and 80px.